# IOS opening other view controller on buttonclick not working with storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I am having a silly problem with opening another viewcontroller on a buttonclick.

On my viewcontroller on my storyboard, I have a button. When a users clicks on this button, a new viewcontroller should be opened. As far as I know, there are 2 ways to do this.

- in code
- on the storyboard itself

Both methods are not working for me.
First the problem with storyboards:

[image]
<sub>(source: [livefilestore.com](https://gk3fag.bn1.livefilestore.com/y2pasvLnATS_KNdDRIJf5MtReTGt7vM_LC7gYmz20VFLQV10AtaIkWVf4D6FaPqR6fZTjGN_ojtS8fn5YoqfexnS98h4ek8lxkoq1vA0dxebOk/Schermafbeelding%202013-11-14%20om%2010.24.53.png))</sub>

I have connected my mainViewController with a navigationController, and I have connected my button with my next view (for adding an item). However, when I run the program, I get the following error:

```
'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
```

I really don't understand this error, because the mainviewcontroller IS managed by a UINavigationController.
So, as this didn't work, I tried to handle it in code. I connected the buttonclick action to the mainViewController.h file and implemented it in the .m file.

This is the action method when a user clicks on the button:

```
- (IBAction)actionBtnAdd:(id)sender {
    AddInventoryViewController *addinvController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddInventoryViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:addinvController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

The other viewcontroller is in the same storyboard, and the ID of the other viewcontroller is "AddInventoryViewController". This gives me the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

Anybody who know the problem? What would be the best approach to solve this?

Comment: Did you try using [self.navigationController pushViewController] instead of presentViewController?

Answer (score 2):

Your navigation controller is not the initial view controller. Select your nav controller on storyboard, go into Attributes Inspector and select "Is Initial View Controller".

Answer (score 0):

Make your navigation controller Initial View Controller.

Then create a push-segue from button to target controller.

Then you can use following method to make some adjustments before pushing:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TargetSegue"]) {
        TargetViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        //vc.items = nil;
    }
}
```

Update: 
There are more options:

1. If your initial view controller is tabbar: Add segue from one of the tabs to navigation controller which contains your view controller.
2. If your initial view controller is another navigation controller:
   Remove navigation controller which contains your view controller. Then add the segue between the thirdViewController and the source from which it is presented. The you can use push segue between the button and the target view controller.
3. If you want to do it programmatically:
   Remove navigation controller which contains your view controller. Push the thirdViewController from your currently presented navigation controller. Push the targetViewController from buttonAction.

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this witouth setting it as initial view controller? Because the initialviewcontroller should not be this view.

Comment: It depends on your storyboard structure. The point is that you need to have connection between your currently presented navigation controller and target view of the segue.

Comment: Currently, I am not using any navigation controllers. I have a Facebook-like slide menu library which handles the main navigation. But the buttonclick navigation isn't contained in this menu, so I can't use it for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the Navigation controller as the first controller[image]

See before the Navigation controller there is the storyboard starting arrow

Answer (score 0):

```
In your Xcode .Click the storyboard on the left side and on top select Editor->EmbedIn->Navigation controller .It will automatically add your navigation controller to the first view controller .Then it would work
```

Answer (score -2):

Under your `IBAction` method instead of using

```
  [self presentViewController:addinvController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

use this code and check

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:addinvController animated:YES];
```